# Sessions automatically generating from servlet/jsp despite having condition : <%@page session="false" %>

Tags: java, jsp, http, session, servlets

I have given a session timeout of 1 minute in my application's web.xml :

```
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

I am also checking at each and every step whether the servlet or jsp is preventing auto generation of new session on its own.

**e.g.**

In each and every jsp file I am giving following sets of instructions to prevent autogeneration :

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

And in the corresponding servlet of every jsp file, I am authenticating the session as follows :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(false);

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

if (httpSession == null) {
        dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/sessionexpire.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
} else {
        // collecting the parameters from front end...
```

Still it is auto generating a new session even at the expiry of current session.
I have written a debug statement in my application that checks for the flaw :

```
System.out.println("session id : " + httpSession.getId());
```

The above statement prints a new session id if the page is reloaded despite session expiration.

What I want, is that once the session gets expired, the corresponding page in my **iframe** should display the message of session expiration and user must be forced to relogin.

But what it does *instead* is that when i *re-click* on the link, it opens the same web page with a brand new session.

I have also placed a HttpSessionListener that does some cleaning job for me.

```
public class InsightHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    InsightDbConn insightDbConn = InsightDbConn.getInstance();

    HttpSession httpSession = arg0.getSession();

    insightDbConn.getFeatureIds().clear();
    System.out.println("feature ids list clear");
}
```

I really dont know what went wrong. Please explain where I am leaving the flaw and session is regenerating by its own.

Comment: Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but aren't iframes ancient?

Comment: Yeah. but that doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Not enough information: please show web.xml, servlet, and your request, to check.

Comment: @Vishal Show servlet where you are creating session first time and how you navigate from that servlet (dispatcher or sendRedirect)?

Comment: Which server are you using ? Weblogic for example, has session settings in weblogic.xml. I would write a filter that checks for valid session rather than delegating the job to individual servlets. If you find that the same problem is occuring in the filter as well, you know that the container is creating the session. If not, the culprit is your code somewhere and you would just have to do the painful debug process